# How to fix "Operator cannot be applied to int[], 'int'?

Tags: java

I am trying to check a condiiton for "teamScore". If it was less than 2 than I want to loop it back.

```
String[] teamName = new String[teamNo];
    int[] teamScore = new int[teamNo];
    String[] Tevent = new String[teamNo];

    for (int i = 0; i < teamNo; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Enter Name of team " + (i + 1));
        teamName[i] = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Name of the events that team"+ (i+1)+"is entering");
        Tevent[i] = scan.next();
        System.out.printf("Enter Total Score of team " + (i+1));
        teamScore[i] = scan.nextInt();

    if (teamScore<2){} 
        // problem here it says operator cannot be applied to int[],'int'.
    }
```

I tried using other declarations like `double`. Pretty sure that's not the case. Any solutions?

Comment: `if (teamScore[i] < 2) `

Comment: Thanks! silly me , i keep forgetting about the fact that i put them into a list.

Comment: @Bonzowo Just a nitpick, but teamScore is an array, not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work:

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int teamNo = 1;
    String[] teamName = new String[teamNo];
    int[] teamScore = new int[teamNo];
    String[] Tevent = new String[teamNo];

    for (int i = 0; i < teamNo; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Enter Name of team " + (i + 1));
        teamName[i] = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Name of the events that team" + (i + 1) + "is entering");
        Tevent[i] = scan.next();
        System.out.printf("Enter Total Score of team " + (i + 1));
        teamScore[i] = scan.nextInt();

        if (teamScore[i] < 2) {
            
        }
    }
```

You need to give the index that you want to get on an array.